# Drivers for AMD Radeon R5 M330 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lenovo, radeon

I would like to ask you for help, with my video card Radeom R5 M330 at my Lenovo 300. I checked some tutorials but its doesn't help. I need stright procedure how to instal drivers for this graphic card. Please help.

Info:

```
Laptop: Lenovo ideapad 300
Graphics card: AMD Radeon R5 M330
Processor: Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Kernel  Linux 4.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
PCI Devices:
-> VGA compatible controller    Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
-> Display controller   Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev 83)
```

I used a few methods and tutorials but results was weak. Where can i find proper drivers? How to install them? How to swich betwen Intel to AMD graphic card? Then, how to check if my laptop truly use AMD graphic card? At the end - How do I remove Intel's driver and why do I need to do it?

Drivers from support.amd.com for M2* and for M340 don't work on my laptop. Package fglrx is not available (or I don't have some PPA), but fglrx-pxpress is only available via apt-get.

More info:

```
# uname -a
Linux lenovo 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


# xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x66 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 4 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:03:00.0


# lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 16 && lspci -vnn | grep -i AMD -A 17
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics [17aa:3809]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon R5 M330 [17aa:3809]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at a1040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon


# inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           tty size: 140x25 Advanced Data: N/A for root


# lsmod | grep -i amd
amdkfd                139264  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
# 
# lsmod | grep -i radeon
radeon               1515520  1
ttm                   102400  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 radeon,i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 radeon,i915
drm                   368640  9 radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

I don't fully understand what this command do/means, below...

```
# glxinfo  | grep -i "opengl renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

# DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep -i "opengl renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
#
# DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep -i "opengl renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD HAINAN (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-41-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)
#
```

Answer (score 2):

Little late, but I can help you to understand those commands. In brief:

**glxinfo**: show information about the GLX implementation

**grep -i "opengl renderer"**: from the output of the above command, will show the lines that contain the string "opengl renderer". In the case of your card, if it is using Mesa or Gallium as renderer.

**DRI_PRIME=0**: Your card have 2 to gpus, and apps can use any of them. This set a variable so the app (glxinfo) will use the "first" gpu, in this case, the Intel one.

**DRI_PRIME=1**: Command the app to use the AMD one.

So in the first case it shows info about the default gpu (Intel), next to the 0 one (same), and then about the AMD one.

In case you want to run for ex. a Steam game using the AMD gpu (which is slightly better):

```
DRI_PRIME=1 steam steam://rungameid/GAME_STEAM_ID_NUMBER
```

**Be sure to not have Steam already running** (because chances are it will be using the default card, Intel, and then the game will run but with that card).

Regarding the driver, my recommendation is to use the ones from the MESA ppa.

Comment: Regarding the driver, there is no fglrx for 16.04.  An R5 330 I think will require using the open source `radeon` driver on 16.04.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

So DRI_PRIME is only variable for my installed gpu driver? or is it parameter for program glxinfo, which shows informaton about my GPUs?

If I set DRI_PRIME=1, my laprop will be using AMD graphic card automatically? 
~$
~$ DRI_PRIME=1
~$ echo $DRI_PRIME
1
~$

How can I check which graphic card is currently using? Or maybe both of them are working parallel? :)

In subject of MESA ppa, @Dobey are you talking about that: https://www.mesa3d.org/install.html ?